# Migration from RxJS 5 to RxJS 6 in Angular 4.3 project

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, migration

So I have a project on Angular 4.3.1 with RxJS 5.4.3? I need to move to RxJS 6 but keep existing version of Angular. I read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) 
guide and steps that i should do is:

1. Update **rxjs to 5.5** version and fix possible errors.
2. Update to **rxjs 6** and install **rxjs-compat** for compatibility, fix possible error that not covered by **rxjs-compat**

And I dont need to change existing code: imports, add pipes and other. Everything should work ?

Comment: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue some days back in my project where installing 'rxjs-compat' fixed the problem temporarily. But, within a week, the project started to throw rxjs errors. Finally, I had to change imports and pipes also. I would strongly recommend to update your code sooner to avoid last minute errors.